# Mirror modifier creating a pointy edge

Tags: mirror

The mirror modifier is creating a pointy edge where I want it flat or round. What can be done to fix this, and the reason for this?

[image: blenderhelp1]

[image: blenderhelp2]

Comment: Turn on merge and clipping in the modifier options - also make sure there is no face between the "halves".

Comment: Thanks！Looks like I had extra faces and edges inside the model.